# Fingerprint Module R305 Output decoding

Tags: c#, bitmap, matching, fingerprint

My hardware counterpart is passing me a series of Hex Codes as the output of an R305 Fingerprint sensor. The output is essentially a 16 x 16 Hex array, that I convert to a byte array of 256.  
I have searched high and low on Google and else where, but not got any information as to what this data represents. The Hardware / IoT guy tells me it is a 8 Bit Grayscale image that contains the BMP of the Fingerprint.  
I have tried to run this through SourceAFIS as the input and it rejects this as Template Data and the BMP I generate from the 256 bit array is rejected as "Source Image is too small".  
I would like to know what does the 256 Hex Code output stand for? Sample Output from R305 sent to my code

```
EF, 1, FF, FF, FF, FF, 2, 0, 82, 3, 1, 5F, 25, 0, 0, FE, 
3E, FC, 2, F8, 2, F0, 0, F0, 0, F0, 0, E0, 0, E0, 0, E0, 
0, E0, 0, E0, 0, E0, 0, E0, 0, E0, 0, E0, 0, E0, 0, E0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 64, 11, E4, FE, 6C, A0, A6, BE, 25, 23, 67, DE, 3C, AA, D1, 
3E, 71, AF, 67, 9E, 3B, 3F, E7, 9E, 3D, B, 50, 7F, 58, 34, 51, 
7F, 27, BB, A6, FF, 24, 41, D0, 5F, 59, 8, 63, 94, 5C, B, A5, 
9C, 33, 39, 67, BC, 73, 13, E4, 75, 74, 10, 4C, 7A, 2B, 1B, CF, 
32, 38, B1, D1, 3A, 36, BC, 11, 1A, 2F, BB, EF, 1, FF, FF, FF, 
FF, 2, 0, 82, 33, 8E, 27, 7B, 6C, C, 4E, 18, 35, 11, 10, 72, 
32, 12, E6, F2, 38, 1E, 8E, F8, 3C, 35, 51, 78, 28, 1E, 66, D3, 
33, A2, E6, 99, 40, 35, E7, F9, 6E, 8D, E2, F6, 2C, 34, D1, 70, 
34, 16, E6, 34, 3B, 96, CF, 8E, 40, 25, 26, B4, 32, 2F, A7, D4, 
36, 24, 8F, F2, 28, 36, 91, CD, 26, 2E, EB, 50, 26, 31, 14, B1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

My conversion procedure from Hex to Byte Array

```
    var templateData = File.ReadAllText(filename);
    var data = templateData.Split(new[] { ',' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    byte[] tmplData = new byte[data.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i
```

Scratching my head since last two days. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Hey did you figure this out finally? I'm also working on a similar project.

Answer (score 0):

Its the Fingerprint template of 256 bytes in hex format. You can use python PIL library.

```
 From PIL import Image

 im=Image.frombytes('L',(16,16),data)

 im.show()
```